# How use getFragmentManager() in static class

Tags: firebase, fragment

```
public static class viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {       
    public void yorum_fragment( final String key){
        yorum.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Comment_Fragment fragment=new Comment_Fragment();
                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("key",key);

                fragment.setArguments(bundle);

                fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.login, fragment);

                fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);

                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

How do I call `fragment` inside this class? `getFragmentManager` needs a non-static class. I tried calling `context`, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved
if we add these lines

```
 FragmentActivity activity = (FragmentActivity)vieww.getContext();
                   FragmentManager manager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
```

working .

Answer (score 0):

The `getFragmentManager` method belongs to the Fragment class.
I created an object of the FragmentManager class and synchronized it with the `getFragmentManager` method.

```
Fragment dd = new Fragment();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager ;
    fragmentManager = dd.getFragmentManager();


            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            AkisFragment NAME = new AkisFragment();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_tutucu, NAME);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```